# Why does Page Directory entries need 20 bits to point 2^10 Page Tables?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

I was learning Linux memory management recently, now I am stopped by the paging mechanism.

As with Regular Paging for 32-bit processors, why page directory entries (32 bits in total) need 20 bits to indicate 2^10 Page Tables? I think 10-bits is just enough and no waste. 
What is wrong with my understanding?

[image: Picture from Wiki]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page has a size of 4096 bytes, i.e., 2^12 bytes.

This means that pages are aligned to a multiple of 4 KB, and that the address of a page is `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx000000000000`.
In other words, a page address needs 12 bits less than the address bus size.
For 32-bit addresses, this ends up being 20 bits.

A page directory entry has 32 bits, so 2^10 of them fit into a 4 KB page.

Comment: Thanks. Is that to say the high 20 bits of Page Directory entries are starting physical addresses of the Page Tables? If so, 20 bits will generate 2^20 addresses, but there are only 2^10 Page Tables.

Comment: The number of page tables has nothing to do with the number of possible addresses.

Comment: I am confused. As I know, the high 20 bits of a PD entry will help to find a specific PG. For example, 00001111 00001111 1111 0000 00000000 will point to a page table whose starting physical addresses is 00001111 00001111 1111, and so forth... I may misunderstand some key points. Thank you.

Comment: It seems only 1024 of these addresses are used, and no matter which of them, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Regular x86 uses 2 level pagetable, but i think the case is that they talk here about one-level page table ... So you have one huge structure with 2^20 entries, each entry associate virtual page address (mentioned 20 bits) with physical page address. Can you provide a link where have you found this picture?

Comment: I think you also misunderstand the paging mechanism. This is not one-level paging.Two-level paging here, Page Directory entries use 20-bits to specify 1024 Page Tables. These 20 bits are same as the high 20 bits of the physical address of the corresponding Page Table (Page Table is stored in main memory, so the CPU need a physical address to find it).

Comment: There are 1024 entries in the Page Directory, and then there will be 1024 entry physical addresses for Page Tables. Right, I believe this is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a 32-bit processor, it will generate 32-bit address.

If an address generated is 32-bit then, addressable memory is 4GB.(As 2^32 = 4GB)

Now, both page table and page directory reside on memory within a single page.

Also, page size is 4kB.

And in page directory and page table, entries always point to border or edge of page table and page directory respectively.

If you divide 4G(1G=2^30) by 4k(1k = 2^10), you'll get 2^20

That is we need 20bits to access all of 4kb chunks within 4GB memory or maximum addressable memory.

That is why, entries for page table and page directory are always 20-bits